# How do I make a <div> dynamically created in an ITemplate class jquery-ui draggable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, devexpress

I have a page that uses a DevExpress NavBar control and an ITemplate implemented class that creates a server-side running div:

```
Public Class NavBarSelectCriteriaGroupItemTemplate
Implements ITemplate
    Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
        Dim templateContainer As NavBarItemTemplateContainer = CType(container, NavBarItemTemplateContainer)

        Dim div As New HtmlGenericControl("div")
        div.ID = String.Format("div_{0}", DataBinder.Eval(templateContainer.DataItem, "text"))
        div.Style.Add("width", "100%")
        div.Style.Add("padding", "5px")
        div.Style.Add("border", "1px solid green")
        div.Style.Add("background-color", "red")
        div.Style.Add("display", "block")
        div.InnerText = String.Format(DataBinder.Eval(templateContainer.DataItem, "text"))
        div.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        'div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('wtf!')")
        div.Attributes.Add("class", "dragme")

        container.Controls.Add(div)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Everything works fine, but now I want to add the JQuery-UI draggable feature to each div instantiated this way.  Initially I tried to add a class attribute named dragme and add a css reference to it on the page calling the ITemplate but with no noticeable result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .dragme {}        
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dragme').draggable();
</script>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got it right , just put your jquery in a document ready block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dragme').draggable();
   });
</script>
```